# Using Flask to determine properties of displayed text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a variables like:

```
myfruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon']
havefruit = [True, True, False]
```

Depending on the user input, the values in `havefruit` might be different. How do I use JavaScript in my HTML file to make the entries in `myfruits` that correspond to `True` be displayed as one color and the entries that correspond to `False` be displayed as a different color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to format the data, and then templates to check if the value is True:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def homepage():
    myfruits=['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon']
    havefruit=[True, True, False] 
    final_data = {a:b for a, b in zip(myfruits, havefruit)}
    return flask.render_template("file.html", variables=final_data)
```

Then, in `file.html`:

```
<html>
   <select id="fruits" name="the_fruits">
      <option value=""></option>
      {%for a, b in variables.items()%}
        {%if b%}
           <option>{{college}}</option>
        {%endif%}

      {%endfor%}
   </select>
</html>
```